# Pricing page: single vs multiple call-to-action button with multiple plans (example inside)

Tags: usability, buttons, layout, e-commerce, conversion

What do you think about having single vs multiple call-to-action buttons? When we were brainstorming our pricing page, half of the room was for single and the other half was for multiple.

I'm trying to find articles that relate to A/B conversion tests regarding this topic and I'm not finding any after several Google searches. If anyone knows of any, could you please share?

As of now, I am for multiple call-to-actions. Why? Being bound to a specific plan gives me the impression that I am safe from going past my needs within the application. This also applies for people that I invite while I am in a trial. In a full featured trial, I have the feeling I need have to micro manage my invites and make sure they don't start using features that aren't core to the needs.

While a full featured free trial is good to explore, I don't feel safe settling down in it since I am unaware if they will warn me when I'm potentially using a plan that exceeds my needs or my budget. Once the trial expires, I don't know how well they handle plan downgrades. I feel more in control selecting what plan I want to do my free trial in, changing plans within the trial if necessary or simply changing after my trial has ended.

**Single call-to-action**

### [image: Basecamp]

**Multiple call-to-actions**
[image: Magento]

Answer (score 1):

I have good experience with using free plan option either as a dimmed secondary option to one business plan. It also works great in a multiplan pricing table.

```
|  Free    |  One man  |  Best offer  |  Awesome  |
-------------------------------------------------
|  signup  |  signup   |    signup    |  signup   |
```

If people choose the free, one man, best offer plan, give them to get a free trial for the awesome plan (with no credit card needed).

It's always nice to what you stucked with when my trials runs out.

I think that is the most transparent pricing/signup model. If you don't have the free plan option, you will find it harder to make people try out your product.

Comment: Really fustrating when companies don't show prices until you have signup for a free trial.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on page to page. When you want a user to do one defined action you direct him with a call to action button.

Giving too many might lead to the analysis paralysis or in most cases it makes all if them look equally important and thus leading to lesser conversions.

Answer (score 0):

**Call To Action**

If by using different plans, users get access to a different set of features, then it makes sense to present multiple call to actions, for the reason you've articulated - you only want to try out the plan that suits your needs and fits your budget, so psychologically you're more confident trying out just that.

If all plans basically offer the same features, but are differentiated by usage limits / caps - e.g. max data size or max logins etc. - then you could show just one call to action.

**During Trial**

If you collect credit card details before trial and automatically charge starting the end of trial, unless user opts out, then every time user takes an action in your trial that changes his consequential bill plan, you should intimate this to the user (within the app).

**After Trial**

If your trial ends with automatic user account deactivation unless he pays, then you need not worry about anything else. User will subsequently pick the plan he wants.

Regardless of anything else, before the trial is coming to an end, you should inform the user (within app and via email) so he can proactively take an action - either pay or cancel his account to prevent automatic billing.